# Is it possible to modify the source code of inbuilt messaging application on an android phone?

Tags: android, messaging

Is it possible to change the inbuilt messaging application on an Android phone? I am doing a project, in which I want to encrypt and store all the incoming messages. Is it possible to see the source code of the the phone's messaging application so that I can add a new function into it, which will encrypt and store the incoming message? I am stuck right now. I read somewhere that if we root our phone, we can change the working of certain inbuilt applications. But even after rooting my phone, I don't know what to do. So please help me with any information you can.

Answer (score 0):

[Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.0_r1/com/android/mms/ui/ComposeMessageActivity.java/) for source code of android inbuilt sms app.